How to resolve apparent conflict between flask-login and flask-htpasswd?
I use login manager from flask-login to protect my routes in a blueprinted flask app. Each user has a unique set of login credentials. But I want to add a site password using flask-htpasswd. My setup in the doc root: app.py is where I register my blueprints including auth, where users log in, the routes for which are found in auth.py. Flask-htpasswd is defined in app.py or the following stderr is returned:
File "/opt/flask-app/flask-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_htpasswd.py", line 158, in auth_failed
[Fri Apr 12 09:56:18.159009 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518005] [remote 172.22.169.58:65226]     current_app.config['FLASK_AUTH_REALM']
[Fri Apr 12 09:56:18.159022 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518005] [remote 172.22.169.58:65226] KeyError: 'FLASK_AUTH_REALM'

This is remedied by adding this stanza to app.py:
#### flask-htpasswd #############################################
from flask_htpasswd import HtPasswdAuth
app.config['FLASK_HTPASSWD_PATH'] = '/opt/flask-app/.htpasswd'
app.config['FLASK_SECRET'] = 'Shock The Monkey'
htpasswd = HtPasswdAuth(app)
##################################################################

auth.py sets up flask-htpasswd with this:
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from flask_htpasswd import HtPasswdAuth
app.config['FLASK_HTPASSWD_PATH'] = '/opt/flask-app/.htpasswd'
htpasswd = HtPasswdAuth(app)

@auth.route('/')
@htpasswd.required
@login_required
def home():
        return render_template('index.html')

This works superficially. But the / route can be sidestepped by hitting /login where Login Manager is called. If I add @htpasswd.required to /login I get this:
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:10.720265 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] (trapped) error reading bcrypt version
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:10.720433 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:10.720451 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481]   File "/opt/flask-app/flask-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/passlib/handlers/bcrypt.py", line 620, in _load_backend_mixin
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:10.720467 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481]     version = _bcrypt.__about__.__version__
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:10.720481 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] AttributeError: module 'bcrypt' has no attribute '__about__'
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628547 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339] [2024-04-12 10:09:21,623] ERROR in app: Exception on /login [GET]
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628681 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628711 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339]   File "/opt/flask-app/flask-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628740 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628768 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339]   File "/opt/flask-app/flask-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628795 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628822 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339]   File "/opt/flask-app/flask-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628848 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628874 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339]   File "/opt/flask-app/flask-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628901 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339]     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628929 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339]   File "/opt/flask-app/flask-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_htpasswd.py", line 206, in decorated
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628955 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Apr 12 10:09:21.628980 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 518481] [remote 172.22.169.58:65339] TypeError: login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'

So if I comment out the call to htpasswd.required in /login it eliminates the parse error but is self defeating. Lastly, I get the above error if I return to the / route once I am authenticated by flask-htpasswd.
Is there any way to resolve the conflict between flask-login and flask-htpasswd? The gatekeeper strategy (a site password using .htaccess) is very useful. TIA!
